# Segmentation fault when blurring an images matrix. [C]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

This is a simplified version of what my program does, my program is intended to create random terrain from a heightmap. This is how I am creating the heightmap.

I have run this through gdb but when I run it through gdb, it never seg faults. When I run it normally however it segfaults. I have no idea why, shouldn't it work the same either way. Is there a tool that I could use to visualize the memory usage of my program?

I am trying to blur a matrix which have access to pixel values. the matrix is indexed row by column.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX(X, Y) ((X) > (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
#define MIN(X, Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    double ** mat;
} grid_t;

static double r2()
{
    return (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ;
}

grid_t * create_grid(int width, int height) {
    grid_t * grid = malloc(sizeof(grid));
    grid->width = width;
    grid->height = height;
    grid->mat = malloc(height*sizeof(double *));
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < height; i++){
        grid->mat[i] = malloc(width*sizeof(double));
    }
    return grid;
}

grid_t * clone_grid(grid_t * grid) {
    grid_t * clone = create_grid(grid->width, grid->height);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < clone->height; i++){
        int j = 0;
        for(; j < clone->width; j++){
            clone->mat[i][j] = grid->mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return clone;
}

void init_rand(grid_t * grid) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < grid->height; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for(; j < grid->width; j++) {
            //srand(time(NULL) + rand()%time(NULL)); uncomment this for the weird effect.
            grid->mat[i][j] = r2();
        }
    }
}


void free_grid(grid_t * grid) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < grid->height; i++) {
        free(grid->mat[i]);
    }
    free(grid->mat);
}

void blur_grid(grid_t * grid, int radius) {
    printf("blurring...");
    grid_t * clone = clone_grid(grid);
    int i, j, x, y;
    for(i = 0; i < grid->height; i++) {
        int x_min = MAX(0, i-radius), x_max = MIN(clone->height, i+radius);
        for(j = 0; j < grid->width; j++) {
            int y_min = MAX(0, j-radius), y_max = MIN(clone->width, j+radius);
            unsigned int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for(x = x_min; x < x_max; x++){
                for(y = y_min; y < y_max; y++){
                    sum += clone->mat[x][y];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            grid->mat[i][j] = sum / count;
        }
    }
    printf("blurred\n");
    free_grid(clone);
}

int main() {
    int width = 512;
    int height = 1024;
    int blur_iter = 1;
    int blur_radius = 2;

    grid_t * grid = create_grid(width, height);

    init_rand(grid);

    int i = 0;
    for(; i < blur_iter; i++) {
        blur_grid(grid, blur_radius);
    }

    free_grid(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

The result should be a matrix with its values tending towards the global average.

The result I get however is a matrix that is often all zeroes.

Comment: the code should just declare the two grids, rather than using calls to malloc() and free(). Suggest: `grid_t originalGrid[ height ][ width ] = {0};' and `grid_t blurredGrid[ height ][ width ] = {0};`

Comment: the `blur_grid()` function is using the full values of all the locations within 'radius'  It should use some percentage of the surrounding values, where the percentage drops the further away from the target location.  Suggest using 25percent of the target, 5percent of all 8 locations that are one location away and 2.5 percent of all 16 locations that are 2 locations away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in blur is that your sum variable is of type unsigned int but should be double.
Further you are making an integer divison.

```
unsigned int sum = 0;
```

should be

```
double sum = 0;
```

Next problem is this line:

```
grid_t * grid = malloc(sizeof(grid));
```

You allocate the size of grid_t* but should allocate the size of grid_t.
This line should be

```
grid_t * grid = malloc(sizeof(grid_t));
```

Just for completness you also need to free the pointer to grid itself:

```
free_grid(grid);
free(grid);
```

Same goes for the clone in blur.